# Populating nested list object of model based on checkbox selections in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC and I find myself a bit on a stick wicket or rather, in a soup kinda situation. This is a length description so please bear with me. And I'm sorry if this seems a bit long and boring :). So, here's my problem :

This is my model.

```
public class SocialAccount
{
    public int SocialAccountID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public int SocialSiteID { get; set; }

    public string SocialAccountUsername { get; set; }

    public string SocialAccountUserID { get; set; }

    public string OAuthToken { get; set; }

    public string Captcha { get; set; }

    public string UserCaptchaValue { get; set; }
}

public class SocialSitePost
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    public string PostAttachments { get; set; }

    public List<SocialSite> SelectedSocialSites { get; set; }

    public List<SocialAccount> SocialAccount { get; set; }

}

public class SocialSite : Audit
{
   public int SocialSiteID { get; set; }
   public string SocialSiteName { get; set; }     
}
```

When a user is successfully authenticated, I store some user details in session and redirect to the home page. This is the code for that:

```
//action method in some Controller
public Login()
{
     //Authenticate user

     //Get all social account related information
     SomeRepository someRepository = new SomeRepository();
     List<SocialAccount> socialAccountDetails = someRepository.SomeMethod(user.UserID);

     //Add social account related information to session
     HttpHelper.StoreInSession("UserDetails", socialAccountDetails);

     //redirect to HomePage
     return RedirectToAction("HomePage", "Account");
}
```

In the HomePage action method, I retrieve the user object from session and check the registered social accounts. I also create a list object of `SocialSite` to maintain a list of all registered social sites. I then pack it in `ViewData` and send it to the view. This is the code for that:

```
//action method in some other controller
public ActionResult HomePage()
{
     List<SocialSite> allSocialSites = null;
     List<SocialAccount> userSocialAccountDetails = HttpHelper.RetrieveFromSession("UserSocialSiteDetails") as List<SocialAccount>;

     if (userSocialAccountDetails != null && userSocialAccountDetails.Count != 0)
     {
          allSocialSites = new List<SocialSite>();
          bool hasFacebookAccount = userSocialAccountDetails.Exists(x => x.SocialSiteID == Convert.ToInt32(CommonConstants.SocialSite.Facebook));
          if (hasFacebookAccount)
          {
               allSocialSites.Add(new SocialSite() { SocialSiteID = 1, SocialSiteName = "Facebook" });
          }
          bool hasTwitterAccount = userSocialAccountDetails.Exists(x => x.SocialSiteID == Convert.ToInt32(CommonConstants.SocialSite.Twitter));
          if (hasTwitterAccount)
          {
               allSocialSites.Add(new SocialSite() { SocialSiteID = 2, SocialSiteName = "Twitter" });
          }
     }
     ViewData["SocialSites"] = allSocialSites;
     return View();
 }
```

I don't have a strongly-typed view. What I need to do is post the user response. So I create a form for POSTing. Now within this form, I want to display a checkbox for all the registered social accounts (ViewData would give me this info). So, lets say,  if user A registered only a Facebook account, then only 1 checkbox representing Facebook should be visible. If user B registered a Facebook, Twitter and Instagram account, then 3 checkboxes should be visible one representing each of these social accounts. I guess you get the idea. This is my code for that:

```
@model SocialSitePost
@{
      using (Html.BeginForm("ProcesssRequest", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
      {
           <div class="divProcessRequest">
               <br />
               <div>
                   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent)
               </div>
               <div>
                   @foreach (var socialSite in ViewData["SocialSites"] as List<SocialSite>)
                   {
                        @Html.CheckBox("SocialSiteID", new { value = socialSite.SocialSiteID, @checked = true });
                        @Html.Label(socialSite.SocialSiteName)
                   }        //Tried this..And am able to display the checkbox

                   @*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedSocialSites.Count; i++)
                   {
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor("SocialSiteID", new { value = Model.SelectedSocialSites[i].SocialSiteID, @checked = true });
                   }*@        //Tried this too..I know this shouldn't work and rightly so, it doesn't work :)
               </div>
               <br />
               <div>
                   <input type="submit" id="btnPost" value="Post" />
               </div>
           </div>
      }
 }
```

Enough said!!! **Now my real problem**:

When the user selects any checkbox, I want to populate the `SelectedSocialSites` property of the `SocialSitePost` object. This is the model whose object the form is posting back. I need to be able to access the `SelectedSocialSites` property in the POST method. This is how my POST method is :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessRequest(SocialSitePost post)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          List<SocialSite> allSocialSites = ViewData["SocialSites"] as List<SocialSite>;        //Can't get anything here
          int socialSiteNo = post.SelectedSocialSites.SocialSiteID;    //This is what I want to be able to do
          return View("HomePage");
     }
}
```

Since, I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, I'm not really sure if this is the right way of doing this. I did try out a few things like EditorFor, trying to send the `SocialSitePost` object the first time the view is rendered (I don't want to do this as it doesn't make any logical sense).

Can someone tell me how I can get the `SelectedSocialSites` property of the `SocialSitePost` class populated in the POST method based on the checkbox selections made by the user?

Also, can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong here as I haven't found any questions here so far on SO which seem similar to this kind of situation?

Comment: I would look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for any suggestions as far as "better ways" of doing something.

Comment: I did not ask for a "better way" of doing this. My question is "Can someone tell me how I can get the SelectedSocialSites property of the SocialSitePost class populated in the POST method based on the checkbox selections made by the user?"

Comment: Since, I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, I'm not really sure if this is the right way of doing this. - This is the statement that my suggestion was based off of.

Comment: As an afterthought or clarification, I asked if there is "something wrong" with my code. "better way" of doing this is something you have inferred, not what I asked.

Comment: This question is similar, and would give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470391/binding-to-a-collection-of-checkboxfor

Comment: Binding collections is probably the most-asked question on SO about .NET MVC. I'd suggest reading some blog posts (like this one: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) to understand how the binding actually works. Then you'll have no problem getting it working.

Comment: @AntP The link that you have provided talks about EditorTemplates which in turn make use of EditorFor. If you would read the question again, you'll observe I did say " I did try out a few things like EditorFor,..". I tried using the EditorFor (EditorTemplate) by reading, yes you guessed it, exactly that post. Though it didn't seem to solve my issue. However, it's a pretty good post. And thanks for the recommendation. Appreciate it!!

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny You've completely missed the point. You need to learn how the *actual binding works* between the POST data and the action parameters. It's not enough to blindly use the HTML helpers and hope they work - you should be looking at the *rendered markup* and determining if it's correct with respect to the parameters you're trying to bind to, which you will be able to do if you read *and understand* the post, instead of just trying to copy the code from it. This is just another variation on a theme of questions where the answer is "learn how model binding works."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that the model is not completely suitable for what needs to be displayed. That is, the format of the model with respect to the view and its representation at the backend is different. Hence, a ViewModel needs to be used here. This is what solved my issue.

These were the ViewModels I ended up designing:

```
public class SocialSiteViewModel : SocialSite
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public string SocialSitePostID { get; set; }
}

public class SocialSitePostViewModel : SocialSitePost
{
    public List<SocialSiteViewModel> SocialSiteViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

And then I could easily use them on the view as such:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SocialSiteViewModel[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SocialSiteViewModel[i].SocialSiteID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SocialSiteViewModel[i].SocialSiteName)
}
```